# How do I register an additional PropertySource with Log4j?

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j2

I've created my own property source for Log4j, but how do I register it? Where do I need to new it up?

```
public class SpringPropertySource implements PropertySource {

    private final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger( this.getClass() );

    private final StandardEnvironment environment;

    public SpringPropertySource( StandardEnvironment environment ) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPriority() {
        return -200;
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach( BiConsumer<String, String> action ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( action );
        environment.getPropertySources().forEach( ps -> {
            if ( ps instanceof EnumerablePropertySource ) {
                EnumerablePropertySource<?> propertySource = (EnumerablePropertySource<?>) ps;
                for ( String key : propertySource.getPropertyNames() ) {
                    String value = environment.getProperty( key );
                    Object clean = key.contains( "pass" ) || key.contains( "key" )
                        ? StringUtils.repeat( '*', 12 ) : value;
                    log.debug( "{} {}", key, clean );
                    action.accept( key, value );
                }
            }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getNormalForm( Iterable<? extends CharSequence> tokens ) {
        return "log4j2." + Util.joinAsCamelCase( tokens );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropertySources are loaded with java.util.ServiceLoader, so you need to define it according to the specs documented at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html.